# Creating DLM object in R : Non symmetric W (error matrix in state equation)

Tags: state-space-models, dlm

I am using DLM package in R for estimating state space model While creating DLM object in R I am getting the following error

***"Error in all.equal(x\$W, t(x\$W)) && all (eigen(x\$W)$values >= 0) : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'"***

Which suggests that We need to have symmetric W matrix for valid DLM.. In my model it is recommended to have W as a lower triangular Matrix....Any idea about the appropriate way to handle this issue

providing R code for the reference

```
Build.dlm.corr.dns =function(param) #correlated factors
{
  G= matrix(param[1:9],3,3) #3X3 matrix
  I= diag(3)
  zero= diag(10^1-10,3,3)
  G= rbind(cbind(G,I-G),cbind(zero,I))

  #16 X3 matrix
  W1= matrix(c(param[10],0,0,param[11],param[12],0,param[13],param[14],
               param[15]),3,3,byrow = TRUE) 
  W1= rbind(cbind(W1,zero),cbind(zero,zero))
  #lower diagonal 3*3 matrix for the error in the state equation
  v1= diag(param[16:31]) # 16X16 for the error in the measurement equation
  f=Nelson.Siegel.factor.loadings(lambda=0.06248*12,maturity=Maturity)
  f= cbind(f, matrix(rep(0,48),16,3))
  #We intialize filter with uncoditional mean and varaiance of beta
  M01= c(mean(beta[,1]),mean(beta[,2]),mean(beta[,3]),mean(beta[,1]),mean(beta[,2]),mean(beta[,3])) 

  c01= diag(diag( cov(beta)))
  c01= rbind(cbind(c01,zero),cbind(zero,diag(10^7,3,3)))
  return(list(
    m0 = M01,
    C0 = c01,
    FF = f,
    GG = G,
    V = v1,
    W = W1))
}


param= c(9.888650e-01, -1.585133e-02,  7.503461e-02,  5.223476e-03,  9.370552e-01,  6.029356e-02, -4.766520e-03,
 7.232573e-02,  8.947844e-01,  5.602845e-06, -4.853184e-06,  9.731190e-06,  4.818279e-06, -4.800690e-06,
 7.176372e-05,  8.378143e-07,  1.647291e-07,  4.398396e-07,  7.803341e-07,  3.211860e-07,  2.924895e-07,
3.581549e-07,  3.461191e-07,  2.933340e-07,  4.310282e-07,  3.914763e-07,  6.358530e-07,  9.016495e-07,
1.487223e-06,  1.750846e-06,  1.969300e-06)


mod=Build.dlm.corr.dns(param)
b= dlm(mod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need a symmetric $W$; it is the covariance matrix of the process noise, hence needs to be symmetric and non-negative definite. You might parameterize a triangular matrix, say $K$: then you have to construct $W$ as $W = K'K$. This allows you to let parameters in $K$ vary freely and still have $W$ symmetric non-negative definite.